# Different ways to cite references in Mathematics

Tags: soft-question

I'm wondering what the different ways to cite references are. I have read about different styles of citation, like

1. APA (American Psychological Association) is used by Education, Psychology, and Sciences
2. MLA (Modern Language Association) style is used by the Humanities
3. Chicago/Turabian style is generally used by Business, History, and the Fine Arts

However, these seem to be limited to their respective fields. What are some of the standard styles used in mathematical literature and papers today? Is there a universal standard?

Answer (score 5):

Mathematics papers are typically written in LaTeX, with BibTex or one of its newer siblings handling the references. The author simply chooses the bibtex style they prefer or the one requested by the publication venue. As the details are then handled by the computer, there is no need to pay any attention to style guides like APA/MLA/Chikago/etc.

Answer (score 2):

Usually: author(s), *title*, journal **volume** (year), publisher. (DOI)

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there is a standard way to cite references, so there is no 'universal standard', but all good styles should include all the important information:

1. Name of authors.
2. Date of publication.
3. Title of article.
4. Journal of publication.

And consistency is very important. Pick a good style and stick to it. As long as you do that I don't think it should be an issue. You can look at existing papers/books to see how your favourite authors style their references section and compare the differences between them.